# Getting a X509Certificate from a SOAP Security Header

Tags: java, security, spring, cxf, x509certificate

Everybody, Hello!

I have a simple stub client for the cxf web-service (spring app). It uses a WSS4JOutInterceptor with  `action = "Signature"` So that, the soap request message is (header):

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.4.3
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1890

  < soap:Header >
    < wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
     <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-2">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
           <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap" />
           </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
           <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
           <ds:Reference URI="#id-1">
              <ds:Transforms>
                 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="" />
                 </ds:Transform>
              </ds:Transforms>
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
              <ds:DigestValue>RJhc1ZVjXdUQEIwLTH356p7H0QY=</ds:DigestValue>
           </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>F0q0NV7kaSbAcsLHxVpYD1bQ1RAJcw6wPapDKAM9PIcs7EuS9S5PlE4cQMfAp1WgsKa91r3op1OQ5UrYmmdj/UneYawdPIYSaoFBGjndTXZnOCKp4YfRTQGZ2EVJRFHJbPsTsqHedPAyJLHhciViguTGeuA0hZAQN97KB/9ZLmY=</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-92A4EB90A2868689DC13289669720792">
           <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-92A4EB90A2868689DC13289669720823">
              <ds:X509Data>
                 <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=1,OU=1,O=1,L=1,ST=1,C=RU</ds:X509IssuerName>
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>1328891280</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                 </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
              </ds:X509Data>
           </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
     </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
< /soap:Header>
```

Can I somehow create a certificate from this data? There is no any data about validation dates or a public key. May be there is a way to insert a certificate inside a header (not via a Reference/SecurityTokenReference tag)???

Progress:

I've read that to embedd a certificate into a request it is needded to use `<entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>`. So that the request changed to:

```
< soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
< soap:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
     <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-A3BCFAE87E12A8813813289737654441">MIICCTCCAXKgAwIBAgIETzVFkDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBJMQswCQYDVQQGEwJSVTEKMAgGA1UECBMBMTEKMAgGA1UEBxMBMTEKMAgGA1UEChMBMTEKMAgGA1UECxMBMTEKMAgGA1UEAxMBMTAeFw0xMjAyMTAxNjI4MDBaFw0xMjA1MTAxNjI4MDBaMEkxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJVMQowCAYDVQQIEwExMQowCAYDVQQHEwExMQowCAYDVQQKEwExMQowCAYDVQQLEwExMQowCAYDVQQDEwExMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCdwxyRNYlWADnTtzH9/s/ehhD2iFzvF2xI+tBNyhbBb98EQNiIFdEegwGPhtd3Cfe1lQqtddWdFX2uLqozMAgd1KzSEuH9lI5DPiir3RfVdy+Irs5ZYiD/H4/DcUMUNyVcWspf9oG25wNdwNHKY8Aqz2269uYMCCoIBuWt6POwFQIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBAGLgTXbn7h2rBjv++6OopDooRifc4e2k+9sSTpLNegs9OvQzR8DpmQ/6Vt0RFprIdXSv+IVMcmL8Q2dmI9v0R61NIhdEjzSVbO2+PF9h1ShUARzMawRC/EOdjwVjDsk1WMxF18+wvH9SQxBSK3H2WpJbDWBxZCOW5CK1N6AKKJiC</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
     <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-2">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
           <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap" />
           </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
           <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
           <ds:Reference URI="#id-1">
              <ds:Transforms>
                 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="" />
                 </ds:Transform>
              </ds:Transforms>
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
              <ds:DigestValue>RJhc1ZVjXdUQEIwLTH356p7H0QY=</ds:DigestValue>
           </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>F0q0NV7kaSbAcsLHxVpYD1bQ1RAJcw6wPapDKAM9PIcs7EuS9S5PlE4cQMfAp1WgsKa91r3op1OQ5UrYmmdj/UneYawdPIYSaoFBGjndTXZnOCKp4YfRTQGZ2EVJRFHJbPsTsqHedPAyJLHhciViguTGeuA0hZAQN97KB/9ZLmY=</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-A3BCFAE87E12A8813813289737654452">
           <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-A3BCFAE87E12A8813813289737654483">
              <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-A3BCFAE87E12A8813813289737654441" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
           </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
     </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
```

Maybe it is simplier to get a certificate from that type of request. But how to do that?

Comment: Hi again :) In one word: you can't infer the certificate from this action. "Signature" is not supposed to send any certificate over the wire. The public part of the key (which was used to generate the signature) should be in client public key ring. The information which is passed in `wsse:SecurityTokenReference` is used to only uniquely identify this key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use a BinarySecurityToken header's element:

```
SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) message;
SOAPMessage doc = getSOAPMessage(soapMessage);

Element elem = WSSecurityUtil.getSecurityHeader(doc.getSOAPPart(), "");
// get a BinarySignature tag
Node binarySignatureTag = elem.getFirstChild();
BinarySecurity token = new X509Security((Element) binarySignatureTag);

// a X509Certificate construction
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(token.getToken());
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
```

as you can see, you also need to use the org.apache.ws.security package.