# Sign SOAP request on client-side with Spring

Tags: java, client-side, spring-ws, sign

I have read the Spring doc regarding [Securing your Web services with Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html) but it looks for me as if the article is just regarding server side and not client side. Indeed, it is working fine for server side with `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` but I need to sign a request to an external Web service.

So, first question. Am I right and chapter 7 of Spring Web Services documentation just apply to server side?

Second. It is possible, to add security, like signed headers, to SOAP requests on client side with Spring in a way similar (simple, elegant) to how it is done on server side?

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9241259/980472) but it looks like signing is done with Apache CXF and this [article](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/ws-security-using-cert-authentication-with-spring-ws-v-how-to-implement-a-message-signing-client/) where  signing is done in a home made way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a clarification: what exactly I want to do is sign the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am afraid I am going to answer my own questions:

**First one**: **NO**. Chapter 7 of Spring Web Services documentation is about both sides, client and server.

**Second one**: Acording with the answer to the fisrt question, **YES**, as it is described on chapter 7 of Spring Web Services documentation.

My error was that I was declaring interceptor in this way:

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <ref bean="wsSecurityInterceptor" />
</sws:interceptors>
```

and this interceptors just affect to server-side Web services. For clients it should be done in this way:

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://localhost:8080/ws-demo/myws" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="wsSecurityInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```