# How do I encrypt Soap message before sending it to Server?

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-security, spring-ws, wss4j

I need to encrypt my soap message with my private key before sending it to server
How do I configure Spring Ws with private key encryption.If any links or code please update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always go with some Apache project like suggested depending on the level of abstraction you want. You can use a lower level library like Apache Santuario, or the balanced Apache WSS4J, or CXF WSS4J. But to me it seems like you want to use Spring. Spring has it's own WSS4J wrapper which I think they call 'Spring-WS', and signing xml (the soap envelope) is possible with it within Spring. http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html <- Chapter 7 of the Spring Docs

You're going to need to create 1 or 2 keystores. One keystore to contain your private keys for signing and the other for your public keys (certs) to see who the service trusts. You can use java keytool or openssl to create these. The following link shows you how to create them. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html#WS-Security-UsingX.509Certificates

You may also want to refer to: [Sign SOAP request on client-side with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281019/sign-soap-request-on-client-side-with-spring) for context

-mario